# not able to update the value in the text box on an Android Device

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium-android

I want to update the value in Call Forwarding of an Android Device.

Code which i am using:

```
        Appium_Mobile_Page.Msisdn.clear();
        Appium_Mobile_Page.Msisdn.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), msisdn);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Appium_Mobile_Page.Msisdn.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ENTER));
        logger.info("Msisdn changed successfully");
```

When I use the above code it clears the value first and changes the value to new one, in addition, Previous value and Junk characters which are in Chinese.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As you are invoking `clear()` why do you want to invoke `Keys.CONTROL, "a"` again?

Comment: I tried removing clear() but it also did not work for me.

Comment: @DebanjanB Using only clear() and sendkeys() renders the previous PhoneNumber and Adds New Phone Number also.

Comment: Can you try to `click()` first, then `clear()`, pause() and then `sendKeys()`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overwriting the existing **msisdn** you may need to *delete* the existing characters and then send the text as follows :

```
Appium_Mobile_Page.Msisdn.click();
Appium_Mobile_Page.Msisdn.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
Appium_Mobile_Page.Msisdn.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.BACK_SPACE));
Thread.sleep(5000);
Appium_Mobile_Page.Msisdn.sendKeys(msisdn);
Appium_Mobile_Page.Msisdn.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ENTER));
logger.info("Msisdn changed successfully");
```

Comment: did not work out have a lot of junk characters post this solution.

Comment: @abhishek Do you have a visibility into the HTML of the element? Please update the question with the HTML

Comment: I have added the snapshot of UI Automator Viewer.